# JS lambda default return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, return-value, default

I am a bit confused with the default return value of lambdas in node.js. I found this link ["Arrow Functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) :

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   return statement.

```
var func = x => x * x;                  
// concise body syntax, implied "return"

var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; }; 
// with block body, explicit "return" needed
```

Which makes it pretty clear, but then I came upon this piece of Express code which I tested that returns the last statement by default without requiring to use "return":

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/api/posts', (req, res, next) => {
  const posts = [
    {
      id: 'sdfj234j654j',
      title: 'First server-side post',
      content: 'This is comming from the server'
    },
    {
      id: '9054jk4ju59u90o',
      title: 'Second server-side post',
      content: 'This is comming from the server!'
    }
  ];
  // this is returned by default and does not require "return "
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Posts fetched succesfully!',
    posts: posts
  });
});
```

So which one is it do I need to use the return statement on lambdas when I use the block quotes to define them or not ? or is there an exception case which I am unaware of?

Comment: Not all JS functions return a value. But once you *do* want to return a value, then the difference between expression-bodied arrow functions to block-bodied ones is more obvious

Comment: Returned where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow function in your example does not return anything. However it writes to the `res`ponse by calling `.json({ /*...*/})`, therefore it kind of "returns" the json to the client.

A simplified example:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("test");
  }, 1);
```

The above code outputs something to the console although nothing gets returned from the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe whatever you have marked as 'returned by default' is not actually getting returned. The function returns `undefined`, as any function without a return statement does. In `app.use`, what happens is, whenever that particular route is encountered, the function gets called, that's all. `res.status` writes to the network only and is not returning any value.